# Live online Oracle Database to test data source connection

Tags: c#, oracle

I am working on C# windows application in which I have used Data link properties to allow the user to connect to variety of Data Source. I want to test Data Source connection to Oracle Database. The problem is we do  not have Oracle installed in our company.

Are there any online live Oracle Database to which I can connect and test connection to Oracle Data source.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any online Oracle database which would let you do something like that; I doubt that *owners* will allow such an action.

I'd suggest you to download & install Oracle 11g XE; it is a small footprint database, free to use (you won't have to pay anything) and will let you test what you're testing.

Download link: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/xe-prior-releases-5172097.html

Installation is simple; more or less a few NEXT clicks; just pay attention to question installer asks (usernames & passwords, ports).

Comment: Okay. I downloaded and installed Oracle 11g XE
This opens a web page - get started "http://localhost:8080/apex/f?p=4950:2:8107036319133702::NO" Now how can I create database and test the connection.

Actually I have never worked with Oracle before.

Comment: Database is already created. Its name is, probably, "XE". At the operating system command prompt, run `tnsping xe` and you should get response. In order to connect to the database, use SQL*Plus - at the command prompt (again), try `sqlplus sys/its_password@xe as sysdba`. As of the page you got - it runs Apex (development tool); if you aren't interested in it, don't use it.

Comment: If you use Docker already there are pre-built Oracle XE images.
I do not know of any online open access Oracle database, but Oracle used to allow people to register for a online APEX account which gave you a user login to a database, but I never tried connecting direct to it, and it was a good 10-12 years ago.

Comment: That "free Apex account" is still available; I use it. But, as far as I can tell, it can't be accessed directly.

Comment: I created workspace and now I am trying to read the EMP Table data. when I try to read the table data i get invalid table name.

Comment: Did you assign schema, that contains the EMP table, to that workspace?